# Could not start a new session - incompatible version- Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
  
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();        
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--user-agent=MiUserAgentPersonalizado");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("XXXX");
```

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

PLEASE, I want to know, How Should I to setting selenium to automatically recognize specify version of Chrome. it worked around two months until yesterday, but today not

Comment: This is probably the answer to your issue in regards to new CfT api for chromedriver releases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76998277/11543023

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDriverManager to **automatically download and set up** the appropriate `ChromeDriver` version based on your installed Chrome browser version.

This way:

```java
// Use the correct version number
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion("116.0.5845.96").setup(); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--user-agent=MiUserAgentPersonalizado");
```

Remember to replace `116.0.5845.96` with **the exact version of Chrome installed on your system**.

Comment: ok, but do i always have to change the version manually? , there is another way, without specifying the version, because chrome will change the version at another time, this application will fail, and changing the version manually adds more maintenance to this application

Comment: You can use `driver.getCapabilities().getCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION)` and deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Using latest version of selenium 4.11.0 solves this problem.
And use;

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```