# WebDriverManager Causing Mismatch ChromeDriver for Chrome Browser version 116.0.5845.111 - (Selenium version - 3.141.59)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

**Exception**:

```java
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111 with binary path
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Code for setting up the `ChromeOptions` and finally creating the webdriver:

```java
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
if (setBrowserUI().equals("yes")) {
  options.addArguments("--headless");
}
options.addArguments("Browser.setDownloadBehavior", "allow");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
base.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Project restriction prevent the upgrade of the Selenium version used. Is there any other way to solve other than updating to Selenium version 4.x ?

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927754/7598774

Comment: I know they asked to upgrade the selenium version to 4.x but here my problem is I can't upgrade the selenium version. Have any solution for it

Comment: Upgrade `webdrivermanager` to `v5.4.1` and see if it works.

Comment: still no luck , facing same error

Comment: Check my answer, try that out.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution will be to upgrade selenium to `v4.11.0` as this version's `SeleniumManager` tool is compatible with chrome version `116`.

Since you do not wish to upgrade selenium, download the `116` version of `chromedriver` and try to set the path of `chromedriver.exe` manually using `System.setProperty`. Refer the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/<full path>/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");        
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

Link to download latest `chromedriver` - https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Answer (score 3):

From Google Chrome v115 onwards, the chromedriver is now available from the new `Chrome for Testing` JSON endpoints. See the announcement here: [ChromeDriver - Version Selection](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection)

Version 3.7.1 of `io.github.bonigarcia.WebDriverManager` does not cater for that new endpoint, so provides the project with the latest chromedriver from the old repository (hence version 114)

`WebDriverManager` catered for this change from version 5.5.0 (latest version at time of publishing this answer is 5.5.2) - see here:

- [WebDriverManager Support for chromedriver 115+](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/doc/asciidoc/index.adoc#support-for-chromedriver-115)

Update the dependency in the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and swtiched to Geckodriver with Firefox.  Geckodriver has never needed to be upgraded in 2 years, unlike the every 2 months with Chrone!